# How to keep android listview highlighted?

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

if I click on a listview item i want to keep the highlight on it. how do i do this?

Comment: dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069393/change-default-onlistitemclick-behavior-of-listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ListView.setChoiceMode(). The "highlight" is meant to disappear when the user touches the screen and trying to change this behavior would be bad for consistency. The choice mode was meant to address this.

Comment: listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE); //doesnt work, when i highlight an item, the highlight disappears

Comment: You cannot keep the highlight like I told you. The choice mode lets you check an item.